# Can you set EditText on append mode after all text have full selection?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a weird scenario. I have an EditText

```
val editText = findView...
editText.setText("Hello")   // prefill some text
editText.setSelection(0, editText.text.length)  // select the full length in the selection
```

Now, the editText would look like `Hello` with the entire word highlighted. If the user type something, say `World`, it would replace the entire selection so now editText only have the new entered word `World`.

Question is, is there a way that instead of replacing the prefilled selection, when user enter text, it will append the text and continue and expand the selection. So in the above scenario, when user type in `World` after the prefill, it will be `HelloWorld` with everything in the selection?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **textWatcher**. Every character you add, you should change selection and add new character to your selection.

Answer (score 0):

add an event on edit text change

when the event is hit remove the selection

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

and position the cursor at the end

```
editText.getText().length()
```

and when the new character is entered do the selection again

```
 editText.setSelection(0, editText.text.length)
```

i hope you get the idea.